# tinymce create own plugin

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I'm trying to create a plugin in TinyMCE. Sofar Google didn't help much: Alot of tutorials that don't work and give alot of errors.

Does anyone have a good tutorial or could someone post some sample code with some info?
I'm using version 3.5.4.

Like I said: I tried searching on Google and also searched StackOverflow.. Nothing usefull.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the tinymce developer documentation is a good way to start: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin .

Comment: yeah, seen that too, but it does not make sense to me... Is that just me or does that sounds a little obvious?

Comment: hmm, this tutorial makes sense to me - where do you have problems?

Comment: I just studied harder on that link you gave me. Makes more sense to me now. Thanks anyway

Comment: link leads to "YOU DON'T HAVE PERMISSIONS TO EDIT THIS PAGE
You need to be an Wiki Member to be able to edit. Login and request access."